# pyplot - plot with a lot of arrow annotations is very slow

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a code that generates plot using python pyplot. This plot is very fast with big amount of points but when I add as well a big amount of arrow annotations the plot is being very slow and each pan or zoom action takes a long time.

This is the line in the code where I add the annotations:

```
    arrow = ax.annotate('', pointA,pointB ,annotation_clip=False, 
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle = 'simple'))
```

Any suggestions how can I accelerate the plot behavior?

Thanks

Comment: how many is "a big amount"? How slow is "being very slow"? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people can appreciate the extent of the problem

Comment: Also, you may want to describe what you are trying to achieve by plotting "a big amount" of arrows, maybe there is a more appropriate solution that to use `annotate` (e.g. `quiver`)?

Comment: OK. big amount is 8000 and very slow is 13 seconds to very small pan movement.
My project is to paint points on a map and to display the possible movement directions from one point to another using the arrows.

Comment: Looks indeed like you would benefit from using [`quiver`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html).

Comment: quiver can supply arrow with head? (to mark the direction)

Comment: I suspect that quiver doesn't fill my need.
I want to plot arrow that start in specific point and end in another point, if I understand well it's impossible in quiver.
Is it right?

Comment: It may not be as straightforward as with annotate, but you simply have to calculate the proper magnitude and direction of each arrrow so it starts from one point and ends at another

Comment: Thanks, magnitude is one of the quiver parameters?

Comment: I have worked to convert the whole code to quiver but the improvement is really a bit..
Any other suggestions?